# Javascript: How can I make that if the user check a checkbox then all nested checkbox are selected too?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let say I have this:

```
<input id="album" name="album" type="checkbox" value="1" /> 
<label for="album">Albums</label><br> 
<ul> 
    <li> 
        <input id="albums_155596787784467" name="albums[155596787784467]" type="checkbox" value="1" /> 
        <label for="albums_155596787784467">Profile Pictures</label><br>        
    </li>                   
    <li> 
        <input id="albums_100358313308315" name="albums[100358313308315]" type="checkbox" value="1" /> 
        <label for="albums_100358313308315">Perfil</label><br>      
    </li>                   
</ul>
```

When the user check the first checkbox I want that all checkboxes in the ul to be checked too.

Also, if any of the checkboxes inside the ul is set to not checked, then the first checkbox should be set to not checked too.

I use JQuery.

Edit:

Also, if all checkboxes inside the `ul`are checked, then the first checkbox should be checked too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("input[name='album']").change(function()
{
    if( $(this).is(':checked') )
    {
        $("input[type='checkbox']","ul").attr('checked',true);
    } else
    {
        $("input[type='checkbox']","ul").attr('checked',false);
    }
});
```

Edited !

And for part 2 of your example :

```
$("input[type='checkbox']","ul").each(function()
{
    $(this).change(function()
    {
        if( ! $(this).is(':checked') )
        {
            $("input[name='album']").attr('checked',false);
        }
        $("input[name='album']").attr('checked',( $("input[type='checkbox']","ul").length == $("input[type='checkbox']:checked","ul").length ));
    });
});
```

Comment: This won't check the main checkbox if all the child checkboxes are checked.

Comment: @Davood: Thanks! you code works like a charm :) Rahul did catch something I didn't, it makes sense that if all checkboxes inside the ul are checked then the first checkbox should be checked too. I will edit the question.

Comment: Quite a bit shorter (and easier) would be `$("input[type='checkbox']","ul").attr('checked',$(this).is(':checked'));`. No need for the if =)

Comment: @Davood: Mmm, this is a little counterintuitive. The 'value' of the checkbox do not change even if the 'checked' attribute changes. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Better to give the ul an id and try the below code.

```
$(function(){
    $("#album").change(function(){
        $("#ulid input:checkbox").attr("checked", this.checked);
    });

    var childCheckBoxes = $("#ulid input:checkbox");
    var totalcheckBoxesCount = childCheckBoxes.length;

    childCheckBoxes.change(function(){
        var checkedBoxesCount = childCheckBoxes.filter(":checked").length;    
        $("#album").attr("checked", totalcheckBoxesCount === checkedBoxesCount);
    });
 });
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WumZR/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#album").click(function(){
    if($('#album').is(':checked'))
        $("input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked','checked');
    else
        $("input[type=checkbox]").removeAttr('checked')
    });
});
```